# JSON returning a strange object in the dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to handle some JSON data. But what I am getting seems to be odd. This is whats returned

```
JSON: {
drugname = ETOFENAMATE;
"prescribing_notes" = "<b>Muscle pain and inflammation:</b> Apply and massage 5-10cm  
strip of gel to affected area.";
rag =     {
    kidney = A;
    lactation = R;
    liver = A;
    pregnancy = R;
    sports = G;
};
```

So drugname is a NSString
rag is a dictionary.

But what should i be doing with "prescribing notes" ?

I put that object into a NSString but the NSString was then NULL at the end. Its HTML so I will be drawing there text inside a UIWebView when i eventually figure out the correct way to handle/extract it into a NSString.

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the JSON object returned is a valid one or not. Use following link to check the validity of  JSON String.

[JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/)